# Android handling broadcasts in different scenarios

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have registered my app to send a broadcast at some particular time using the alarm manager, and have set a receiver to listen to that broadcast.

Now there can be 2 cases:

1. The OS feels there is a memory crunch and removes the app from the background. The android documentation says that the OS will ensure that my receiver receives my broadcast. Is it true ? How can I test such case ?
2. A user decides to close my app using any task killer. Will I receive broadcast in such case too ? If not then is there any way to handle such case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The OS feels there is a memory crunch and removes the app from the background.

Your receiver will not be in memory anyway. Your receiver for use with `AlarmManager` should be registered in the manifest, and those receivers live only as long as it takes for `onReceive()` to run.

> Is it true ?

Yes.

> How can I test such case ?

Every test will test this case, if your receiver is registered in the manifest.

> A user decides to close my app using any task killer. Will I receive broadcast in such case too ?

On Android 2.1 and earlier, no. Task killers there also eliminate scheduled alarms.

> If not then is there any way to handle such case ?

Not really, which is why this was eliminated with Android 2.2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please be more specific in telling me what was eliminated in 2.2 ?

Comment: @frieza: Task killers can no longer kill tasks, generally speaking. With respect to `AlarmManager`, a task killer can no longer remove scheduled alarms.